# Puzzle Ring - Does Kadala have a chance of dropping this?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can the Puzzle Ring (2.0 version) drop from Kadala? Is there even a slight chance of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a chance. The only legendaries that are not given by Kadala are [Horadric Cache Only items](http://www.diablowiki.net/Horadric_Cache#Horadric_Cache-only_Items)

Answer (score 2):

Since Patch 2.0.5 Kadala can drop every Legendary item (Torment and non-Torment) except the Legendary items from the [Horadric Caches](http://www.diablowiki.net/Horadric_Cache). (Thanks  WizLiz)

Cause Puzzle Ring is a (non-Torment) Legendary item, Kadala can drop it.

[Patchnote 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/)

> Kadala
>
> ```
> Can now drop Torment only Legendary items
> ```

Comment: Puzzle ring is not a torment only item.

Comment: Plus she can't give cache only legendaries so "every legendary" is wrong ;)

Comment: I never said that Puzzle Ring is a Torment only item. And WizLiz thats right of course. Sorry that i missed that.